# How to check laravel collection is empty in blade file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have added the condition like this @if(!empty($param)) but not working.

Comment: Please share the code of your blade file, route file, controller and model.

Answer (score 5):

assuming `$param` is a collection here, you can use [`isEmpty()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-isempty) or [`isNotEmpty()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-isnotempty) method like this:

```
@if($param->isNotEmpty())
```

Or

```
@unless($param->isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isempty` method of laravel collection to check whether a collection is empty or not. For more detail you can check it in their document.

[Laravel Collection: isempty Method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-isempty)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `count()` method and do something like this :

```
@if($collection->count())
```

More details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-count).

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
@if(count($param) > 0)
```